# nhibernate criteria set the alias of a subclass parent?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I have an abstract base class that contains a property called "DateCreated"; it has a number of child classes, some of which link to each other.

When I try to query against one of the child classes, I get an ambiguous column error with DateCreated, as it is contained in more than one table.

Here is a snippet of the criteria:

```
.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
.Add(Projections.GroupProperty(Item.LinkField + ".Id"), "Measure")
.Add(Projections.Count("Id"), "StatCount")
.Add(Projections.GroupProperty("lnk." + Item.LinkTextField), "MeasureText")
.Add(Projections.SqlGroupProjection("MONTH(DateCreated) As [period]", "MONTH(DateCreated)", new[] { "period" }, new IType[] { NHibernateUtil.Int32 })))
```

Is there any way for me to specify as part of the criteria an alias for the join between a subclass and its parent? I don't think `CreateAlias` will work as there are no joining properties.

1. If I prefix `{alias}.` to `DateCreated`, it will prefix `_this` in the generated SQL and while that is the alias of the current table, it is not the alias of the parent table which contains the `DateCreated` field, so the column is not found.
2. If I prefix `this_1_.` to `DateCreated` which is the alias NHibernate gives to the parent table in the generated SQL, the query works, but I think that is probably a bad idea.

Here is the generated SQL from NHibernate:

```
SELECT TOP (5) this_.incidenttype_id      AS y0_,
               Count(this_.module_id)     AS y1_,
               lnk1_.dicttext             AS y2_,
               Month(this_1_.datecreated) AS [StatFrequency]
FROM   tblincident this_
       INNER JOIN tblmodule this_1_
               ON this_.module_id = this_1_.id
       INNER JOIN tbldict lnk1_
               ON this_.incidenttype_id = lnk1_.id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tbldictcode lnk1_1_
                    ON lnk1_.id = lnk1_1_.dict_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tbldictimage lnk1_2_
                    ON lnk1_.id = lnk1_2_.dict_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tbldictsdscategory lnk1_3_
                    ON lnk1_.id = lnk1_3_.dictimage_id
WHERE  this_1_.customer_id = 2
       AND this_1_.isarchive = 0
       AND this_1_.isactive = 1
       AND this_1_.isconfidential = 0
       AND this_.incidentdate BETWEEN '2012/01/01' AND '2013/04/01'
       AND this_1_.isactive = 1
       AND this_1_.customer_id = 2
       AND this_1_.orgunit_id BETWEEN 3 AND 1000
GROUP  BY this_.incidenttype_id,
          lnk1_.dicttext,
          Month(this_1_.datecreated)
```

In this example, tblIncident is the subclass of tblModule
DateCreated is contained within tblModule
The only reason the above criteria worked is because I passed in the "this_1_" as that is whats automatically assigned to it by nhibernate. using "{alias}" would output "this_1" which would cause an error.

I obviously want a way to specify that alias.

Comment: Can you post the SQL generated ?

Comment: @frictionlesspulley I have updated the question and provided sql.